# nuxtjs create .htaccess file after run npm run generate

Tags: bash, vue.js, shell, nuxt.js

I would like to make a script that create .htaccess file in /dist folder after I run `npm run generate` automatically.

now I need to run

```sh
cat > .htaccess << EOF
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
EOF
```

after `npm run generate` but I want it to do automatically.

Do you have any solution to do this?

Comment: You could create a `.sh` script where you do your `cat` thing and chain it like `npm run generate && ./my_custom_script.sh`.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

- `touch my_custom_script.sh`
- edit it and put this inside with your favorite editor (like `nano` or `vim`)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat > .htaccess << EOF
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
EOF
```

- add the execute right to the file with `chmod +x my_custom_script.sh`
- run it like this in your CI: `npm run generate && ./my_custom_script.sh`