# How to include an .htaccess file wit Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js app with an `.htaccess` file.
The problem is that when I execute `nuxt generate` in the terminal, my `.htaccess` file disappears. What can I do to include my `.htaccess` file when I execute `nuxt generate`?

Comment: You could probably put it into the `/static` directory: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static#static-directory

Comment: I also have this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844473/8816585 Even tho, I'm not sure it's needed if you want something static.

Comment: Thank you it's working. I thought that if was putting my .htaccess file into the static directory, it would stay here.

Comment: I have posted my answer!

Comment: could also move or make the file dynamically with a custom build module https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/modules/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your `.htaccess` file into the `/static` directory, more info on that in [the doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static/#static-directory).
That way, you will have direct access to it once pushed to production.

Otherwise, you can also use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71844473/8816585) if you need something more customizable.